# PHP MySQL convert time format

Tags: php, mysql

i've the following code

The date format in the database is (yyyy.mm.dd) so I want to convert/format it to (dd.mm.yyyy)

This code is reading the date from the database

```
                    {
                      echo '<span class="badge badge-success" style="background-color:red;">Nicht Verf&uuml;gbar</span> <p><i class="fas fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:Red;"></i> Vergeben bis :<span style="color:red;font-weight:600;">';
                      echo htmlentities($result->VerfuegbarAb);
                      echo '</span></p>';
                    }
```

My question, how I can get this into my code? I don't know how to add a time format into this code and yes this code looks like horrible and would be a better solution but i'm learning still php and i'm going trough everything to get better :) Hope someone can help me would be amazing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime('2020-05-03'));
```

OR:

```
$testdate = '2020.05.03';

echo date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime(str_replace('.','-',$testdate)));
```

**In your case:**

```
echo date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime(str_replace('.','-',$result->VerfuegbarAb)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
$newLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
$formatted_date = strftime('%d. %B %Y',$result->VerfuegbarAb);
```

For this to work, the locale 'de_DE' needs to be installed on your system.

P.S: Kudos to you for using `htmlentities()` as a beginner after fetching data from the database.
It's a great habit and often forgotten.